Artin's "Autoduality of the Jacobian"
In some of his papers (for example, in "Formal groups arising from algebraic varieties" with B. Mazur), M. Artin cites

M. Artin and B. Wyman, Autoduality of the Jacobian, Bowdoin College, 1967 (mimeographed notes).

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find these notes anywhere. I wonder if someone here has a digital copy of it.

It's available here. Padding Padding Padding

thank you !  I just located my copy of those Artin notes, with a friend to whom I gave them 10 years ago, but now I needn't trouble him.

I do not know where to find those Artin notes.  However, perhaps you know James Milne has posted notes treating the auto duality of the Jacobian on his page that may be of use to you, and I recall at least that Milne was present at that Bowdoin meeting.  (Of course I think you could also ask Mike.)
If interested, see page 104ff of these notes: https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AV.pdf
